# Add angular field validation dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I am trying to create form builder application in Angular.js and I got stuck on validating fields. Angular provides great validation but one thing is missing for my usecase, and that is turning various validation on / off dynamically. I want to let my user add new form fields and then specify a validation (Angular default minlength, maxlength, ...) for each field alone.

Lets say that I want to create a button, that will add / remove minlength validation on a specified field (fields are stored in my model and are displayed through custom form and field directives), how should I do this?

I created a simple Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/pCXgwgnNbZkcAcl263JN?p=preview can you tell me what shoud be inside the `toggleValidation()` function?

**HTML**

```
<div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine }" class="form-group">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" class="form-control" name="name" />
          <p class="help-block" ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine">Validation error.</p>
        </div>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="toggleValidation()">Toggle minlength validation</a>
```

**JS**

```
validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

    $scope.toggleValidation = function()
    {
      // ???
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using something like http://formly-js.github.io/angular-formly/#!/ to dynamically generate forms from a set of JSON objects. Then it would very very easy to toggle certain validation methods on and off.

Comment: Thanks! that provided me with inspiration needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I should try something like this:

```
validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

  $scope.toggleValidation = function(validationFlag) {
    $scope.validationIsOn = validationFlag;
  }

  $scope.minlengthValidation = function (field, minlen) {
    if ($scope.validationIsOn) {
      return (field.length >= minlen);
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

});
```

*Note: this code is not real code, but it just wants to give an idea to build the real code...*

Comment: I was thinking about more generic solution, not just minLength but at least all default Angular validation options (except of require, which has its own if), is there any generic solution for this?

Comment: I.e., you want to enable or disable all valitations at once?

Comment: No, just one type of validation at once for one of the fields. When you let user define fields for dynamic forms, you want to give him options to set a validation for that field. And this validation is dynamically set for each field.

Comment: I see, it makes sense. You should give more details about the way your user specifies the validations required for each field... However, I suppose the logic I did show in my answer could be easily generalized...